# Querying free space in LocalFileSystem on the MBED board

Tags: lpc, mbed

Is there any supported API to get free space in the `LocalFileSystem` on an MBED board? I've tried `statvfs` but it doesn't seem to work... Any ideas?

I guess I could simply list all files and subtract the total from the total size, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

This is what I tried:

```
long GetAvailableSpace(const char* path)
{
  struct statvfs stat;

  if (statvfs(path, &stat) != 0) {
    // error happens, just quits here
    return -1;
  }

  // the available size is f_bsize * f_bavail
  return stat.f_bsize * stat.f_bavail;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I ended up iterating over all files and calculating it:

```
#define MAX_STORAGE 512000

int LocalFileSystemFreeSpace(){
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME];
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    int total = 0;

    d = opendir("/local");
    if(d){
        while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
            sprintf(filename, "/local/%s", dir->d_name);
            int size = FileSize(filename);
            total += size;
            //printf("%s -> %d\r\n",filename,size);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }

//    printf("Total files: %d\r\n", total);
//    printf("Free: %d\r\n",MAX_STORAGE-total);

    return MAX_STORAGE-total;
}

int FileSize(char * filename){
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp==NULL){ 
        return 0; 
    }
    int prev=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz=ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return sz;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible right now. [Semihosting](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_pge1358787046598.htm) is used for the LocalFileSystem API, and the only commands that are currently implemented are [here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/mbed_semihost_api.c#L25). Nothing for free disk space...

Comment: Thanks Jan, that's what I suspected.